# Present continuous tense

Tags: present-continuous

Is it grammatically correct to say: I'm taking a shower today?

I've read that we can use present continuous with today, these days, etc.

I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: What do you think? We generally do not answer "is this correct" questions. Anyway, why wouldn't it be right?

Comment: I've got the answer. Thank you.

Comment: The important point is that although "I'm taking a shower today" uses the progressive aspect, its meaning cannot be accounted for in terms of progressive aspectuality. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's example is fine. But note the difference between...

> 1: *I'm going to work today* (I ***will*** go to work soon, but I'm ***not yet*** at work)
> ...and...
> 2: *I'm having a day off work today* (something I'm probably ***currently / already*** doing).

With those examples it's fairly clear whether the reference is to something *current, ongoing* or *future, planned*. But...

> 3: *I'm taking a shower today*
> ...the speaker probably *isn't* currently showering, so it's more like my #1 above, whereas...
> 4: *I'm wearing casual clothes today*
> ...might mean either ***currently***    OR ***in the near future*** (maybe I haven't even got dressed yet! :)

Usually, context makes it obvious whether the action/activity specified using Present Continuous is ongoing OR planned, ***and*** whether it's a relatively brief action, OR something that lasts "all day".

---

It's purely a personal opinion, but I have the feeling we're at least *slightly* more likely to use Present Continuous for an "extended" activity (that might take all day) if such a statement is adverbially modified by, for example, ***today***. Hence...

> 5: *I'm lighting fireworks today*
> 6: *I'll light a firework today*
> ...are arguably more likely than...
> 7: *I'll light fireworks today*
> 8: *I'm lighting a firework today*

...but not everyone will necessarily agree with me on that point of style.

Comment: Shouldn't the action take all that period of time for us to be allowed to talk about it in that way? For example for being allowed to use present continuous with " these days " should the action be repeated in all those days or it's okay for it to happen in one of those days?

Comment: *I'm having sex at least twice a month these days* is fine, even though it's strongly implied that I'm *not* currently having sex on *most* days. Don't overthink this one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - er... [edited].

Comment: Yes. The real world nature of the action, how long it takes or might last, affects our interpretation of the sentence. "I am sick today": I'd take that to mean that you are sick now and expect to be sick all day. "I am working today": I'd guess you mean that you are putting in a normal work day, 8 hours or so. You may or may not be working now. "I am drinking a cup of coffee today": I wouldn't suppose that you mean that you are going to slowly sip on one cup of coffee and drag it out all day. More like, sometime today you will spend a few minutes, maybe half an hour, drinking coffee.

Comment: @Jay: I don't know why someone *downvoted* the question, but feasibly it's because the all-important clarification (that the OP thought we couldn't / shouldn't use the continuous verb form if the activity doesn't last for at least *most* of the time-frame mentioned) only appears in a comment, rather than in the question text itself. But I thought it was *at least* as important to address ambiguity regarding whether the specified activity has actually *started* at time of utterance. In both cases, the ambiguity is normally resolved by context (if indeed it matters at all; maybe it doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *I'm taking a shower today.*

Yes: it's grammatically correct.

It's important here to distinguish the syntactic category of *aspect* and the semantic category of *aspectuality*. There is a difference.

Although [1] uses the progressive aspect ("be"+*ing* verb), its meaning cannot be accounted for in terms of progressive aspectuality.

In other words, it doesn't mean that my showering is in progress right now, but that I intend to take a shower later today. Grammarians call this the progressive futurate.

Similar examples of progressive aspectuality include:

> [2] *I'm phoning her tonight*.
>
> [3] *She's having her operation tomorrow.*
>
> [4] *Ed is having dinner tonight with Gill.*

[2]-[4] are like [1] in that they too have a future time reference.

Comment: Thank you so much for considering my question.